# Plone FTP connection

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I am using Plone 4.1.4 and trying to connect site via FTP. I made configuration change to enable FTP but while connecting via FTP client connect has made but no file listing.It's giving 550 permission denied. Do I need to make any other changes?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying with the `admin` super-user account or with a regular account? (ISTR regular accounts lacked permissions for some parts of FTP/WebDAV aroudn that time.)

Comment: with admin super-account.

Comment: Have you tried passive mode?

Comment: @webbyfox Ah - I misunderstood who you were in IRC, apologies!

Comment: Look like it's something to related to firewall and setup of server. I tried same thing on local computer and it worked as expected. Thanks for looking into this.